# Preserving attributes of KML file when loaded into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml

How do I upload a KML file into QGIS with the attribute data intact? It is present in Google Earth but not when imported into QGIS?

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/sites-of-biological-importance-sbi-in-greater-manchester-as-at-2015-04-28

This is the website which contains the data I need. I need to show the site names on my map, but I am currently unable to do this.
My coordinate reference system is: OSGB 1936/BNG (OTFR Enabled).

Comment: What steps have you taken thus far and where are you running into issues?

Comment: I have made a shapefile which shows the attribute data but appears in the wrong location, it is separate to my other data which is on the CRS mentioned above. I have imported the KML file which appears in the correct place aligned with my other data but has no attribute data with it. I really need to know how to attach attribute data to the KML file. I have downloaded the CSV file which comes up in excel with all the data is there a way I can attach this to the KML IN QGIS? Thanks

Comment: As a workaround you can convert KML into some easier format with ogr2ogr.  Command would be like `ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes output.sqlite gmeu_sbi.kml` Spatialite does not alter the attribute names by cutting them to max. 10 characters allowed in shapefiles so I recommend that.

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the site, and found a good way to do this.  KML is not the best format for handling attributes (as you found), but they also allow you to get the data as a CSV, which is a great format.

Download the CSV, in QGIS, choose Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...  Pick WKT as the geometry interpreter, and choose the field that says it has WKB geometry in it (which actually looks more like WKT anyway).  I had not used this dialog  before, and it's actually really great--more straight-forward and flexible than the one in ArcGIS.

That should do it.  Once the layer is on the map you can save it as a shapefile if you like, and also assign the correct CRS to it.

EDIT: I found that the data from the site you linked is actually in WGS48 Web Mercator, EPSG 3857, not the national grid system as it claims.

Comment: Thanks I have now got it uploaded with the attribute data available but it is still not in alignment with my other data. My other data all aligns but this KML will not! The other data i'm using is on a national scale that could be why? But I have no choice but to use this national data. http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/WebStore?xml=environment-agency/xml/ogcDataDownload.xml If you scroll to the bottom of this I used Sites of Special Scientific Interest (3 from bottom) downloaded as a shapefile and I need it to align with this. Thanks

Comment: So basically I can get the KML in the correct location but with no attribute data. The CSV will go in the wrong location but with attribute data. Please see if you can try and align the CSV with the Sites of Special Scientific Interest? @mr.adam

Comment: Ok, it's a CRS issue.  While the first site says that the data is in the national grid, it's actually in Web Mercator WGS 1984 projection, which is EPSG 3857.  The shapefile is in the national grid.  Once you correctly define the CRS for each layer, they line up just fine.

Comment: So I need to change the SBI shapefile to the Web Mercator WGS 1984 projection? To do this do I right click that layer and click 'Set Layer CRS'? And then I change both to this Web Mercator (...) projection? Thanks

Comment: Each layer in the table of contents needs to have the correct CRS assigned to it.  The SBI layer needs epsg 3857, and the sites of special interest needs the national grid.  Yes, that's the way you set the CRS, and you find the ones you need with the filter.  [Here's](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Getting_started_with_crs_and_projections) some information on how QGIS handles CRS.

Comment: Thankyou, I am trying to locate the espg 3857 on coordinate systems of the world but it is not there? I tried filtering it by typin 'Web Mercator' but it does not appear?

Comment: In QGIS, when you are in the layer properties and you click "Specify" for the CRS, you get a dialog that has a line in it for Filter.  Type 3857 in here, and you'll find it.  It's called WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (I think ArcGIS calls it Web Mecator).

Comment: Thank you so much its worked! Ive spent the last 2 days trying to do this, so I really appreciate you going through it with me!

Comment: Sure. Understanding how QGIS handles CRS makes everything easier.  Also, incorrectly documented data makes things a little difficult too... 3857 is super common world-wide (it's used for all web maps) so it's a likely candidate for a rogue projected coordinate system that comes from the web.

Answer (score 1):

Download the kml, and go to this page: http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php you can export here the kml to shape format, and then load to qgis (and change the wgs84 system to epsg27700 (osbg36). Hope it helps.

Comment: When Ive tried this i've uploaded the kml file, but its a google earth one so it wont work. It says no entities found. From the first link I posted in my question is there a way to download the KML without it opening in google earth? (so its its own file?) Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Converted the KML to Shapefile using FME

[image]

FME simple process is (read then write)
[image]